# How to make a web3 transaction?

Tags: ethereum, web3js

How to make web3 transaction? I stack at:

And getting errors: Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address
But my addresses are all right.

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
            from: paymentAddress,
            to: paymentAddress,
            value:Web3.utils.toWei(amountEth.toString(), 'ether')
        }, (err, transactionId) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Payment failed', err);
                divMessage.style.display = "block";
                $('#divMessage').html('Payment failed');
            } else {
            }
        })
```

And get error web3.toWei is not a function

Comment: maybe https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38034/using-sendtransaction-in-web3-js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solve it. I have an issue with copy past. I probably get virus and when I copy my adress I get other adress.
I checked my real address with:

```
window.ethereum.selectedAddress
```